# Android Robolectric unit test for Marshmallow PermissionHelper

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I wanna learn Robolectric to use it for unit tests on an Android Marshmallow app. I wrote a `PermissionHelper` with some methods to make permission handling a bit easier. To get started with unit tests for this class, I am trying to test the most simple method:

```
public static boolean hasPermissions(Activity activity, String[] permissions) {
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        int status = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission);
        if (status == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the Robolectric test that I wrote so far:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class PermissionHelperTest {

    private PermissionHelper permissionHelper;
    private ShadowApplication application;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        PictureActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(PictureActivity.class).get();
        permissionHelper = new PermissionHelper(activity, activity, 1);
        application = new ShadowApplication();
    }

    @Test
    public void testHasPermission() throws Exception {
        String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        boolean hasPermissions = permissionHelper.hasPermissions(permissions);
        Assert.assertEquals(false, hasPermissions);

        application.grantPermissions(permissions);
        hasPermissions = permissionHelper.hasPermissions(permissions);
        Assert.assertEquals(true, hasPermissions);
    }
}
```

The first Assert works (no permission granted). But after granting all permissions via the ShadowApplication they are still denied in the next Assert.

I think that the `PictureActivity` created with `Robolectric.buildActivity()` is not using the ShadowApplication for the permission checks. But `PictureActivity.getApplication()` does not give me a `ShadowApplication` to call `grantPermissions` on. How can I test this?

I am new to Robolectric and unit testing on Android...so if there is any other framework that makes this easier/possible: I am open for suggestions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of using `ActivityCompat` I'm using `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` which receives a context, so send a mock of the context and return permission granted, this is work for us:

Instead of:

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission);
```

use

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission);
```

then in your text you can send a mock directly to your `hasPermissions` method and stub the result as:

```
Context context = mock(Context.class);
when(context.checkPermission(eq("YOUR_PERMISSION"),anyInt(),anyInt())).thenReturn(
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

Comment: Is this part of **Mockito**, or **Robolectric**

Comment: Which part? `ContextCompat` is part of Android support package and the rest is regular mockito

Answer (score 15):

From Robolectric 4.2 you can use:

```
Application application = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
ShadowApplication app = Shadows.shadowOf(application);
app.grantPermissions(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Answer (score 13):

Your problem is that you're using a different application to grant permissions, not your own.

Instead of this:

```
application = new ShadowApplication();
```

you should get a shadow of **your** application, like this:

```
application = Shadows.shadowOf(activity.getApplication());
```

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you. After the change I got another error that AndroidHttpClient is missing, but that's an easy fix discussed here: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1862