# Robolectric + Mockito + Marshmallow + Permissions

Tags: android, mockito, robolectric, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to write a unit test for a method that depends on the result of `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(..)`. To do so, I need to do two things:

1. call `Robolectric.shadowOf(activity.getApplication).grantPermission(...)`
   **which depends on an Activity built by**  `Robolectric.buildActivity(PictureActivity.class).get()`
2. call `Mockito.verify(activity).someMethod(wasCalled)`
   **which depends on an Activity built by**
   `Mockito.mock(MyActivity.class)`

So when I create my Activity with Robolectric, I cannot use the Mockito.verify.
And when I create my Activity with Mockito, I cannot use the Robolectric.grantPermission.

How can I cover this? I'm new with both frameworks, so maybe I am missing something simple.

Comment: I would wrap logic in some permission checker and mock it in activity tests. However, the testing of this permission checker will bring the same problem. I will check if Robolectric supports anything with permissions otherwise I think you need to write own shadow

Comment: Why are you calling activity.getApplication() when you could be using Robolectric.application instead?

Comment: @robinj because then I would grant permissions to the wrong application. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031301/android-robolectric-unit-test-for-marshmallow-permissionhelper

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't checked it out in detail, but since today it should be possible to make use of [GrantPermissionRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule.html) by using the new [Android Testing Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Read my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/37704872/1345391 in which I explain a way to workaround the checkSelfPermission problem with robolectric